# get all actions that taken by user using signals in django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, action, django-signals

I am very new to Python. I have created a model with all the data of User and creating the signals for registering user, logging in application, deleting an user and creating a group of users. I have to get all the action performed by the user for particular domain. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance...

Here is the code written below

```
class User(models.Model):

MALE = '1'
FEMALE = '2'
GENDER = (
    (MALE, _("Male")),
    (FEMALE, _("Female"))
)

ADMIN = "1"
ADVERTISER = "2"
USER = "3"

ROLE = (
    (ADMIN, _("Admin")),
    (ADVERTISER, _("Advertiser")),
    (USER, _("User"))
)
email = models.EmailField(_('Email address'), max_length=254, unique=True) name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=30, null=True, blank=True) screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender =  models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("select gender."),
        max_length=1,
        choices=GENDER
    )
role = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=ROLE,
        verbose_name=_("Select Role.")
    )

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance = User
        actions = action.send(instance, verb='user created')
        profile = User(user=instance, actions=actions, object_id=instance.id, object_repr=instance.name)
        profile.save()

@receiver(post_delete, sender=User)
def delete_profile_for_new_user(sender, deleted, instance, **kwargs):
    if deleted:
        instance = User
        actions = action.send(instance, verb='user_deleted')
        profile = (user=instance,actions=actions)
        profile.delete()

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def sig_user_logged_in(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("user logged in: %s at %s" % (user, request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']))

@receiver(user_logged_out)
def sig_user_logged_out(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("user logged out: %s at %s" % (user, request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']))

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_group_for_users(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Group(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```

Comment: Why do you use signals? You may create a middleware class to record all API actions including user creation.